# Is it possible to unselect the current date in jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using a datepicker, which is always visible on the page, and tied to a hidden `<input>`.
Depending on the user interactions on the page, some dates can get dynamically disabled (via [beforeShowDay](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay)).

The problem is, this allows to disable a date which has been previously selected:

[image]

To avoid this, I'd like to *unselect* the current date prior to refreshing the datepicker.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: The datepicker is attached to a `div`. Clear the selected value like this:

```
$('selector').datepicker('setDate')
```

This will unselect whatever day is selected.

Comment: I don't want to specify an arbitrary date either, as sometimes, all possible dates might be disabled!

Comment: That doesn't work either: `$('selector')` points to a `<div>`, as the datepicker is always visible, and `.val()` has no effect. The date is not unselected from the datepicker.

Comment: That doesn't work either, sorry: `setDate` without parameters just resets the datepicker to the current date. That's actually contrary to what the doc says: "... or null to clear the selected date."

Comment: Just found that [a bug has been filed](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8159) on this very problem.